# Sorting database data with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Newbie here.  I am having some trouble with PHP some code.  I currently have 1 database, consisting of two tables.  The two tables are labeled as `members` and `member_stats`.  The members table consists of 3 columns `(Fname, Lname, MemberID)`, the `member_stats` table consists of 11 columns `(user_name, first_name, last_name, avatar, num_friends, num_checkins, total_cards, total_selfmade_cards, total_followings, total_photos)`.

I am fetching the data from my database with

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM member_stats ");
```

I am then displaying the data into html table on the page with the following code.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><div class='user_nav_btn open' ><img src='" . $row[avatar] . "' alt='' /></div></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['MemberID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['num_friends'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['total_cards'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['num_checkins'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['total_selfmade_cards'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['total_followings'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['total_photos'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

I am trying to get the table to print all the rows of data based on the value of `total_cards` in order from highest to lowest.  No matter what I have tried, I haven’t been able to get it to work.  I have only been met with errors on everything I have tried.  Any suggestions?  I have looked over http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php several times with no luck.

Comment: do the ordering in the query `order by total_cards`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the firt comment drive you on the good way, you don't need PHP sorting as you did, just a Query SQL is sufficient.

```
SELECT * FROM member_stats ORDER BY total_cards ASC
```

By default a SELECT is ASC, i just added for knowing he can do (ASC | DESC) sorting in the Query.

Comment: WOW, i really was over thinking this and making it harder than it needed to be i guess.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method would be for you to update your SQL; you can order your server requests the results.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM member_stats ORDER BY total_cards";
```

You also have the `ASC` (ascending) or `DESC` (descending) keywords which will determine the order from ascending to descending.

This will query your database to get the data in the order of `total_cards`

You can also get all of the results in an array, and then sort it using some Javascript table library, and manipulate it that way.